# How to use .join() with push and replace together?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I need to do is to add a delimeter between an array elements.

I have:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    response.push(
        $sce.trustAsHtml(        
           myResource.replace('[[RESOURCE]]', ResourceValue)
    )
     response.join('');
 );
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried add a join() in different places, but none of them seemed to work. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried to place the `response.join()` after the for loop?

Comment: Ideally, you will first push all the values on the `response` array, then you call `join()` on that array when you have pushed all the values, i.e, after the loop, like `let joinedRes = response.join('');`. The new variable `joinedRes` will hold a string with the joined values.

Comment: I think you need to make `join(',')` where `,` will be a delimiter

Comment: I already tried to use `.join(' ')` outside the for loop, but a result is the same. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    response.push(
        $sce.trustAsHtml(        
           myResource.replace('[[RESOURCE]]', ResourceValue)
    )
);
response.join(' ');
```

Comment: Maybe you need response = response.join(' ') because the join doesn't occur in place.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly. I needed to do as you said in your comment. You saved my day!

Comment: You're welcome. Choose one of the answers as the solution to your problem just in case someone else is having the same problem. A solved question is better :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = ['data1','data2','data3','data4'];
var joinArray = "'" + data.join("','") + "'";
console.log(joinArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.join('')` returns a string. Assign that string to a variable.